# Python subprocess awk command in a function, taking element from list as argument

Tags: python, awk, subprocess

I want to subprocess an awk command with a list element as argument.

With a single argument, and from a shell prompt, it's prety simple:

```
$ awk -F "," '/US/ && /00001/ {print $1","$3}' stock_inventory.csv  > pretest_00001.csv
```

So using a list, I put it all in a Python script like:

```
import subprocess

mylist = [00001, 00002, 00003]

def myawk(item_code):
    subprocess.call("awk -F "," '/US/ && /%d/ {print $1","$3}' stock_inventory.csv  > pretest_%d.csv") % item_code

for i in mylist:
    myawk(i)
```

I did it wrong somewhere. Could Popen have been of any help?
What about lambda in this case?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: hi andry... might I ask what is the error you are receiving? I can not reproduce the scenario at this moment but I can help with it if you provide me some more details

Comment: It is probably not the best solution you are using, but I guess your direct issue is that you have `% item_code` outside the paranthesis. It should go inside, directly after the string you want to format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.

I found a more elegant way to resolve it, though it's not through a Python script but a Bash one instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=("00001" "00002" "00003")

for i in "${arr[@]}"

do

    cat stock_inventory.csv | grep $i | grep US | awk -F "," '{print $1","$3}' > pretest_$i.csv

done
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps ditch python and do all in `awk`?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";
             n=split("00001,00002,00003",item)}
       /US/ {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
               if($0~item[i]) 
                 print $1,$3 > "pretest_"item[i]".csv"}' stock_inventory.csv
```